# ¿Como imprimir algunos caracteres de la tabla de Ascii? Java POO

Tags: java, poo, ascii

Tengo que imprimir por consola los caracteres especiales, numéricos, mayúsculas y  minúsculas de la tabla *ASCII*; Pero no me imprime nada. Probé sacarle el `for` y solo me sale este signo:

por cada método que llamo en el main.
Les dejo el código que hice.

```
public class TablaDeAscii {

    private char numeros;
    private char minusculas;
    private char mayusculas;
    private char especiales;


    public TablaDeAscii() {
        this.numeros = numeros;
        this.minusculas = minusculas;
        this.mayusculas = mayusculas;
        this.especiales = especiales;
    }

    public char getNumeros() {
        char numerico=0;
        int contadorN=0;
        for (int i = 0; 32 >= i && i <= 122; i++) {
            if (48 >= numeros && numeros <= 57) {
                contadorN ++;
                numerico+=contadorN;
            }
        }
        return numerico;
    }

    public char getMayusculas() {
        ;
        int contadorMa=0;
        for (int i = 0; 32 >= i && i <= 122; i++) {
            if (65 >= mayusculas && mayusculas <= 90) {
                    contadorMa++;
               mayusculas+=contadorMa;
            }
        }
        return this.mayusculas;
    }

    public char getMinusculas() {
        char minuscula = 0;
        int contadorMi = 0;
        for (int i = 0; 32 >= i && i <= 122; i++) {
            if (97 >= minusculas && minusculas <= 122) {
                contadorMi++;
                minuscula+=contadorMi;
            }
        }
        return minuscula;
    }

    public char getEspecial() {
        char especial = 0;
        int contadorE=0;
        for (int i = 0; 32 >= i && i <= 122; i++) {
            if (32 >= especiales && especiales <= 47) {
                contadorE++;
                especial+= contadorE;
            }
        }
        return especial;
    }
}

public class PruebaAscii {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TablaDeAscii tabla1 = new TablaDeAscii();

        System.out.println(tabla1.getEspecial());
        System.out.println(tabla1.getMayusculas());
        System.out.println(tabla1.getMinusculas());
        System.out.println(tabla1.getNumeros());
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, al publicar pon el cuidado necesario para que tu pregunta tenga una correcta ortografía y el código quede con el formato correcto. He tenido que editar tu pregunta para mejorarla en ambos aspectos y te dejo este comentario, dado que ya no eres un miembro nuevo. En StackOverflow la idea es que tanto preguntas como respuestas sean de buena calidad. Te invito a leer [ask] y la [ayuda del editor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifica tu bucle for, para que te imprima de la siguiente manera:

```
for (int c=32; c<128; c++) {
    System.out.println(c + ": " + (char)c);
}
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS :D , era eso ! Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Complemento la respuesta de @David Davila con este pequeño truco para recorrer la tabla ascii sin hacer castings.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (char c = 'a'; c < 'z'; c++) {
        System.out.println("Symbol " + c);
    }
}
```